# Property does not exist on type '{}' when using MatDialog

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, mddialog

I updated angular from 4.0.0. to 4.4 . when running my project I've got some errors.

I get this error :

> modif.service.ts (36,33): Property 'tache' does not exist on type
>   '{}'.

**modif.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { ModifComponent } from './modif.component';
import { TacheService } from './tache.service';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import { MatDialogRef, MatDialog, MatDialogConfig } from '@angular/material';
import { Tache } from './tache';


@Injectable()
export class ModifService {
  private headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
  private tachesUrl = 'api/taches';  // URL to web api

  taches: Tache[] = [];
  tabTaches() {
    return this.taches;
  }
  selectedOption: string;


  constructor(private http: Http, private tacheService: TacheService,
    public dialog: MatDialog) { }


  openDialog(tache: Tache) {
    let config = new MatDialogConfig();

    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ModifComponent, config);
    dialogRef.componentInstance.tache = tache;
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => { // Line 36
      this.selectedOption = result;
      console.log(this.selectedOption);
      tache.name = this.selectedOption;

      this.tacheService.modifyS(tache);

    });
  }
}
```

I use this service to change a todo item name by displaying a dialog box.

Update  : I include modif component also

**modif.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { MatDialogRef } from '@angular/material';
import { Tache } from './tache';
import { TacheService } from './tache.service';
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material';


@Component({

  selector: 'modif',
  templateUrl: './modif.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modif.component.css']


})

export class ModifComponent {
  tache: Tache;

  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ModifComponent>) { }



}
```

Before Update everything was workig ok.

Comment: Please provide modif.service.ts in the description

Comment: Could you add the ModifComponent ts?

Comment: Yes I have added them